# Find a word which is after a pattern and before another pattern using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find a word in a file which is after a particular pattern and before a particular pattern.
Here is the content from the file:

```
print("Hi", "My name is", "Tej");
```

So, I want to get the word `Tej` alone and store it into an array. Similarly, I have many such files with similar pattern as above but with different names, so I want to push all those names into an array. i.e. I want the words from the from the files which are after the pattern `print("Hi", "My name is", "` and before the pattern `");` .

Sometimes, the space after the commas are missing.

I wrote the script for opening files and passing the file handle to a function to search for the word which is after and before the pattern. The code for the function is as follows:

```
sub search{                                    
my $file_handle = shift;
while (<$file_handle>)
{
/.print("Hi", "My name is", "[\s]+([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/ ;
push @array, $1;
}
}
```

I know the regex doesn't work but I am not sure about how to find the word I need. Any help provided is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
sub search {                                    
    my $file_handle = shift;
    while (<$file_handle>) {
        if (/print\("Hi", ?"My name is", ?"([^"]+)"\);/) {
            push @array, $1;
        }
    }
}
```

I escaped the special characters inside the regex (i.e. `(` and `)` in this case), and I used `"([^"]+)"` to match all the non quotes inside the quotes.

The question mark after the space makes the presence of the space optional.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You logic helps.

Comment: Tip: `if (/print\("Hi", ?"My name is", ?"([^"]+)"\);/) {
            push @array, $1;
        }` can be written as `if (my ($name) = /print\("Hi", ?"My name is", ?"([^"]+)"\);/) {
            push @array, $name;
        }` (to avoid using globals unnecessarily) or even as `push @array, /print\("Hi", ?"My name is", ?"([^"]+)"\);/;`